# QTableWidget setItem() segmentation fault using Qt

Tags: qt, segmentation-fault, fault, qtablewidget

I'm using the following code to add a row to a QTableWidget.

```
QTableWidgetItem *item = new QTableWidgetItem(fileName);
item->setCheckState(Qt::Checked);

QComboBox *cmb = new QComboBox(this->list);
cmb->addItem("one");
cmb->addItem("two");

this->list->setRowCount(this->list->rowCount()+1);
this->list->setItem(this->list->rowCount()-1,0,item);
this->list->setCellWidget(this->list->rowCount()-1,1,cmb);
```

There are 2 columns in the table. 'item' is placed in the first one, 'cmb' in the second one. Using this code I can succesfully add 1 row to the table, but when I try to add a second row, I get a segmentation fault.
It crashes on the this->list->setItem() call.

Any idea of why it crashes?

Thanks!

Comment: tried your code and it works fine for me; no segmentation fault adding more then 1 line to the table widget. I'm using ubuntu 10.10 Qt 4.7.1

Answer (score 0):

I can't tell why your code doesn't work as is, but do this:

```
int N = list->rowCount(); //The problem may lie in multiple rowCount() calls somehow
list->insertRow(N);
list->setItem(N,0,item);
list->setCellWidget(N,1,cmb);
```

Also, is there a particular reason you use 'this->'?  It's generally completely redundant in this situation.

Comment: I just use this-> because I think it's more clear.. .
I now solved it by using setCellWidget twice, and removing the setItem..

Answer (score 0):

I had code that was extremely similar to you and it crashed as well...

```
QTableWidgetItem* columnOne = new QTableWidgetItem();
columnOne->setCheckState(Qt::Checked);
QTableWidgetItem* columnTwo = new QTableWidgetItem("Some Text");

int row = tableWidget->rowCount();
tableWidget->insertRow(row);
tableWidget->setItem(row, 0, columnOne);
tableWidget->setItem(row, 1, columnTwo);
```

However, if I changed the order of the setItem calls so that the check state is added last then it worked. So this is code worked...

```
QTableWidgetItem* columnOne = new QTableWidgetItem();
columnOne->setCheckState(Qt::Checked);
QTableWidgetItem* columnTwo = new QTableWidgetItem("Some Text");

int row = tableWidget->rowCount();
tableWidget->insertRow(row);
tableWidget->setItem(row, 1, columnTwo);
tableWidget->setItem(row, 0, columnOne);
```

Answer (score 0):

**Problem** is in this row (you named some list and QTableWidget the same: "list"):

> this->list->setRowCount(this->list->rowCount()+1)

`this->list->rowCount()+1` will always return 0+1=1, so that is why you can add first, but not second row to your table.

**Solution**: name your QTableWidget other than "list", for example:

```
this->myTableWidget->setRowCount(this->list->rowCount()+1);
this->myTableWidget->setItem(this->list->rowCount()-1,0,item);
this->myTableWidget->setCellWidget(this->list->rowCount()-1,1,cmb);
```

Answer (score 0):

This issue in my code was happened because of logic in cellChanged SLOT. I was trying to setText in QTableWidget that hasn't been actually created yet.